# Python: How to split string containing extra delimeters as value

Tags: python, dictionary

I am using python and reading "attribute.txt" file

Contents of attribute.txt file is in "Key: value" format, as shown below:

For e.g.

```
data: Test data
version: 3.1
system: windows
```

My Python code to read and split contents line by line looks like this.

```
 with open(self.attrib_file) as f:
            self.txtdict = dict(l.strip().split(':') for l in f)
```

Above code is working fine, but failing for data that have colon ":" character in value part of it.

For eg.

```
data: Test data
version: 3.1
system: windows: unix   <-- This line will fail as it have two colons.
```

How can i make sure that "key" system have value "windows: unix" ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the keys do not have semicolons:

```
print(dict(l.strip().split(':', 1) for l in f))
```

**Output**

```
{'data': ' Test data', 'version': ' 3.1', 'system': ' windows: unix'}
```